# An IDE for a small business

Tags: ide

I told a friend I would help her out with a website for a small business.  It would just have the typical Home, About, Contact Us etc for a small business.

For work, I’ve worked on websites in angular, ExtJS, etc using IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ with typically a java back-end.

Would all of this be a bit of overkill for a typical small business web site that's not going to do anything very complicated?  Would I be better off using WordPlay or some other non-coding web builder?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be coding the project I recommend using VSCode IDE(https://code.visualstudio.com/). It's simple to use, lightweight and offers a lot of extensions to ease and make efficient front-end (and back-end) development. Make sure to install extension LiveServer to quickly start your own localhost. Optional you can add other extensions like snippets, formating extensions etc..

For non coding project you can visit the Wordpress site and create a website with Elementor. It's easy to use and offers plenty of features to create a small business site. Here is a quick guide to get you started (https://blog.hubspot.com/website/how-to-use-elementor)